# Why is this mongo sort not working

Tags: mongodb

I try to sort a collection:

```javascript
var assortiment_producten = db.get('assortiment_producten');
assortiment_producten.find({
    product_ID: product_ID
}, {
    sort: {
        subcategorie_ID: 1
    }
}, function(err, docs) {
});
```

But the received docs are not sorted by subcategorie_ID

Do I miss something here???

Comment: can you add sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation on `find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), the first argument to find is a filter, and the second one is a projection. Hence your sort syntax will be interpreted as a projection, which is not what you want. For sorting, you need to use the `sort()` function.

The following works for me:

```
> db.assortiment_producten.insert({ product_ID : 1, subcategorie_ID : 'A' })
> db.assortiment_producten.insert({ product_ID : 2, subcategorie_ID : 'B' })
> db.assortiment_producten.insert({ product_ID : 0, subcategorie_ID : 'C' })
> db.assortiment_producten.insert({ product_ID : 0, subcategorie_ID : 'D' })
> db.assortiment_producten.insert({ product_ID : 0, subcategorie_ID : 'A' })
> var product_ID = 0
> db.assortiment_producten.find({ product_ID : product_ID }).sort({ subcategorie_ID : 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5298b024de2b8992960081a0"), "product_ID" : 0, "subcategorie_ID" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5298b001de2b89929600819e"), "product_ID" : 0, "subcategorie_ID" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5298b01fde2b89929600819f"), "product_ID" : 0, "subcategorie_ID" : "D" }
```

Comment: Your solution workshop for me too. But in my nodeJS app .sort is not valid. Maybe because I use Monk?.

Comment: how do you connect to mongodb with nodeJS? Using the npm monodb library? Some sample code would be helpful.